# square graphics error with DOSBox under Ubuntu 18.4

Tags: ubuntu, dosbox

I have installed DOSBox under a remote Ubuntu server. When  I start Dosbox remotely with Termius on a Mac I get the following picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9lgm.png)

I have tried some parameters in the Dosbox.config file but with no results.
What is the wright solution?

Comment: What makes you think Termius can display graphics?

Comment: Dosbox starts in Text mode (80x25). Quart graphics is text mode graphic with IBM characters. You can read the text in row first line. But then it goes wrong.